# Using rocksdb::Iterator and Column Family is not working

Tags: c++, iterator, key-value-store, column-family, rocksdb

I have the following piece of code:

```
rocksdb::DBWithTTL* db = ...
rocksdb::WriteOptions writeOptions;
rocksdb::ColumnFamilyHandle cfHandle = ...

std::string keyPrefix = "prefix";
std::string key = keyPrefix + "_key";
std::string value = "value";
rocksdb::Status s = db->Put(writeOptions, cfHandle, key, value);

rocksdb::ReadOptions readOptions;
readOptions.prefix_same_as_start;
readOptions.snapshot = db->GetSnapshot();
rocksdb::Iterator* iterator = db->NewIterator(readOptions);

rocksdb::Sliced start = rocksdb::Slice(keyPrefix);
for (iterator->Seek(start); iterator->Valid(); iterator->Next()) {
  printf("hello");
}
```

The `printf` is never hit.

However, if I change the `Put` line to:

```
rocksdb::Status s = db->Put(writeOptions, key, value);
```

Meaning, removing the `column family handle`, I'm getting the line printed fine.

I'm guessing the iterator API should take the column family into account, but I couldn't find any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the missing API call was:

```
rocksdb::Iterator* iterator = db->NewIterator(readOptions, cfHandle);
```